# Istio egress routing with multiple external hosts through egress gateway not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, istio-gateway

We have an use case where we need to create egress gateways to communicate with multiple external hosts. We followed the documentation given in https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-https-traffic. It works if we have a single external host but with multiple external hosts it doesn't. Just to test our use case we are trying to configure two external hosts and this is the error we see :

```
 bash curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer                                                                                                                                                             │
│ bash   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                                                                                                               │
│ bash                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                                                                                                                 │
│ bash   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --: │
│ bash curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer                                                                                                                                                             │
│ bash   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                                                                                                               │
│ bash                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                                                                                                                 │
│ bash   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0                                                  │
│ bash curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Expected behavior
Traffic should be routed to google and paymenttools.com.

Steps to reproduce the bug

Service Entries for both of the external websites

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-04T09:48:00Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: test-egress-networking-www.google.com-443
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "402044469"
  uid: 3cc0c95d-f4fb-4bd8-a87f-00d552105458
spec:
  exportTo:
  - .
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
  ---

  apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-05T08:16:04Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: test-egress-networking-www.paymenttools.com-443
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "403158012"
  uid: 838580e7-0982-4ef4-903a-6ab738a1e051
spec:
  exportTo:
  - .
  hosts:
  - www.paymenttools.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
```

Configure Virtual Services for both

```
 apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-04T09:52:02Z"
  generation: 5
  labels:
    app: test-egress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-egress-networking
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-egress
    helm.sh/chart: network-3.12.1
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: www.google.com-443
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "404913509"
  uid: 39c8513b-4a82-4f48-a319-b538f4d0ff53
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-bf7f5eb02957dae90addc9c99754ff5d2aedf1821-egress-gateway
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - www.google.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-test-egress-networking-egress-gateway.test.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
        subset: bf7f5eb02957dae90addc9c99754ff5d2aedf1821f5dd513f720b15f4ae3
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-bf7f5eb02957dae90addc9c99754ff5d2aedf1821-egress-gateway
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - www.google.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: www.google.com
        port:
          number: 443
  ---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-05T08:16:04Z"
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app: test-egress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-egress-networking
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-egress
    helm.sh/chart: network-3.12.1
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: www.paymenttools.com-443
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "404913970"
  uid: 73f5cf05-45e3-415d-8e5a-62f8e64b0592
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh
  - istio-9b2f56608b26eca7193652502e7d626c9771601a0-egress-gateway
  hosts:
  - www.paymenttools.com
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - www.paymenttools.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-test-egress-networking-egress-gateway.test.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
        subset: 9b2f56608b26eca7193652502e7d626c9771601a0d95c1594eb39262610c
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-9b2f56608b26eca7193652502e7d626c9771601a0-egress-gateway
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
      - www.paymenttools.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: www.paymenttools.com
        port:
          number: 443
```

Configure Gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-05T08:16:04Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    app: test-egress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-egress-networking
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-egress
    helm.sh/chart: network-3.12.1
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: istio-9b2f56608b26eca7193652502e7d626c9771601a0-egress-gateway
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "404902076"
  uid: 8ab999fa-f9d8-4103-9f26-fdcfc0fa1ae8
spec:
  selector:
    istio: test-egress-networking-egress-gateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - www.paymenttools.com
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-04T09:48:00Z"
  generation: 6
  labels:
    app: test-egress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-egress-networking
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-egress
    helm.sh/chart: network-3.12.1
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: istio-bf7f5eb02957dae90addc9c99754ff5d2aedf1821-egress-gateway
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "404902432"
  uid: 2f89af05-8ce8-43f1-b34d-534cf8e1ca8c
spec:
  selector:
    istio: test-egress-networking-egress-gateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - www.google.com
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
Destination Rules
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test-egress-networking
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: test
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-04T09:48:00Z"
  generation: 6
  labels:
    app: test-egress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-egress-networking
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-egress
    helm.sh/chart: network-3.12.1
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: test-egress-networking
    helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: istio-test-egress-networking-egress-gateway
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "404915054"
  uid: 1f6f140b-8002-40ff-8ef8-042e4721f489
spec:
  exportTo:
  - .
  host: istio-test-egress-networking-egress-gateway.test.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: bf7f5eb02957dae90addc9c99754ff5d2aedf1821f5dd513f720b15f4ae3
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
      portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 443
        tls:
          mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
          sni: www.google.com
  - name: 9b2f56608b26eca7193652502e7d626c9771601a0d95c1594eb39262610c
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
      portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 443
        tls:
          mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
          sni: www.paymenttools.com
```

How was Istio installed?
Helm

> Version istioctl version client version: 1.16.1 control plane version:
> 1.18.0 data plane version: 1.18.0 (63 proxies)
>
> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25",
> GitVersion:"v1.25.4",
> GitCommit:"872a965c6c6526caa949f0c6ac028ef7aff3fb78",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-11-09T13:28:30Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.19.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
> Kustomize Version: v4.5.7 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1",
> Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.5-gke.1400",
> GitCommit:"4eb57372b0f0ac0023caca078161b7518

I have raised the same question [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/45883) but haven't got any feedback. Did any one faced similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using ISTIO_MUTUAL will not work with an endpoint like "google.com".

If you want to originate the TLS connection, you have to use `SIMPLE` instead in your DestinationRules.

Check the [docs here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings-TLSmode).

Comment: its still not working . I see a different error now -
```
bash curl: (35) OpenSSL/1.1.1t: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
```

I kept all other configuration same. Just to elaborate we are using a test container which curls https://www.google.com/

Also ,yI know why  ISTIO_MUTUAL setting won't work?

Comment: ISTIO_MUTUAL won't work because Google has no clue about your certificates, and you can do mutual TLS with it. 

Also, your egress GW configuration is configured on port 80, yet in your VS you're sending traffic to port 443. I'd suggest you get the Istio example you link to working first, and then expand with an additional host.

Comment: I have copy pasted the wrong version of the gateway. Currently we have implement the same version as given https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/. It works if you have single external service to communicate. But it doesn't work if you have more than one external service.

Comment: Your configuration must be wrong. I just went through the example in Istio docs and added "google.com" as another ServiceEntry, and I can make requests to both endpoints without issues.

Comment: Yes, we fixed  configuration issue. And we had issues with network policies. Network policies were actually causing the issues. Not it working as expected. Thanks.